# Are there any ways to make rum cookies other than baking them?

Tags: baking, cookies

In the 1935 Walt Disney animated short `The Cookie Carnival' three tipsy rum cookies sing that all other cookies are baked in a pan but a rum cookie always is stewed.

Is that just a play-on-words or can rum cookies be prepared without baking? I have read about boiled cookies but, like bagels, the last step is to bake them.

Comment: Hmmm . . . . I think "stewed" here is intended as a play on words, as a joke, and not meant to be taken literally.  In informal English "stewed" can mean drunk.  There are things such as steamed cakes/puddings/buns, but texture-wise these are nothing like "cookies".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rum balls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rum_ball) are prepared without cooking. I’m not aware of any cookie-like thing which is simply boiled or “stewed”, and I doubt anything one could produce that way would be recognizable as a cookie.

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking about as well. They are part of a „cookie platter“ and often interpreted as cookies, although they are more like truffles.